# How to select from winforms app

Tags: winforms

i created this winforms app and i have text results being displayed in a MessageBox. I came to copy my results only to realize i cannot copy from a MessageBox. what can i use that will enable me to come from or should i just save my results into a file and copy from that?

```
MessageBox.Show(theStringBuilder.ToString());
```

I tried a listbox:

```
Results_lst.Items.Add(theStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Also a label:

```
Results_lbl.Text = theStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always roll your custom `MessageBox`. You can add copy to clipboard option to your `MessageBox` to keep it simple.

**Also**

you can copy text to clipboard everytime you show a messagebox.

```
var msg = theStringBuilder.ToString());
Clipboard.SetText(msg);
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```